# Timeout decorator - custom Timeout exception

Tags: python, oop, exception, timeout, decorator

I have a function `get_dist` that gets distances of a zip code from 3 cities in Texas. The problem is, `pgeocode` times-out sometimes. I don't see any custom argument for timeouts. Ideally, if it times-out I would like to add dummy values to the variables and move on. I was playing with `timeout_exception`, but could not come up with anything that works.

The class is kind of pseudocode.

```
import time
import timeout_decorator
import pgeocode

class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
    def add_vals(self):
        return aust, houst, sa
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

dist = pgeocode.GeoDistance('us')

@timeout_decorator.timeout(25, timeout_exception=MyException)
def get_dist():
    aust = dist.query_postal_code(zip, '78701')
    houst = dist.query_postal_code(zip, '77021')
    sa = dist.query_postal_code(zip, '78205')


get_dist()
```

Comment: What happens when `pgeocode` times-out without your decorator? If it raises an exception you can use `try` / `except` to trap it. In fact you could easily write your own decorator.

Comment: Nothing happens it just sits there and never finishes. Which is why try and except doesn't work.

Comment: ActiveState has a different [timeout decorator](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577853-timeout-decorator-with-multiprocessing/) you could try — otherwise you should contact the author(s) of the `timeout_decorator` library,